# How to select idle worker without the screen jumping to the worker?

Tags: starcraft-2

Every time I select "idle worker", the screen jumps to the worker. This completely throws me off during, say, an attack. Is there a way I can select my workers and tell them to harvest minerals without looking at them? Shift-click, I believe, selects them all, but there is still the unnecessary jump.

Comment: Not that I know of, besides which minerals would they goto? The closest? Farest? etc... What if it's in an enemies base? would it return home to mine? Would it mine at the enemies base?

Comment: `Ctrl` + `F1` selects all idle workers, I don't know if it jumps the screen, so you could try that. But @Viper_Sb's point remains, you will need to move the screen to minerals to harvest them; there is no 'harvest closest resource' button.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, there is a 'return resources to base' command, I suppose if your idle worker is carrying minerals/gas, this might get them back to mining, but that seems unreliable.

Comment: It may be realistic to click minerals through a minimap - I inject larva this way. Sure, mineral patches are even smaller than a hatchery...

Comment: @Viper_Sb - I can still see the scenario being useful. what if I wanted to select an idle worker to quickly move him to where I'm currently looking, whether that be to begin mining a mineral patch I'm looking at, repair a structure under attack, or simply move with my army?

Comment: @robotnik yes if you want to more him with you then sure, you specifically asked about minerals so was answering that as well.

Comment: @Wikwocket I am pretty sure they removed the "return resources button / funktion" in HOTS. It was part of the workers programming returning to the CC etc. after gathering. It now just return to the nearest CC etc. and repeat unless told not to. If you have a worker not doing anything with gas or minerals, you will have to click the worker to the CC etc. or the mineral or gas.

Comment: @The_Jsaur I dont think there is a way not to jump to your idle worker unless you select them all.

Comment: They actually do have a return resources to base command. :)

Comment: Got it, thanks everyone. Hmph, I was hoping for a better way. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

If you select all idle workers, then use a location hotkey, you can make the scvs extremely fast. Set the location hotkeys to each base and when you make buildings use the location hotkeys to rally the scv back to mining every time. Then just double click hotkeyed army to get right back. It's a little distracting but worth it.

Comment: You don't even need to set a location hotkey. Backspace (I think?) will automatically cycle through your nexus / CC / hatcheries.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Backspace is the default key for the "View Base" hotkey. http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Hotkeys#In-Game_hotkeys

Comment: @RavenDreamer while you are correct. It is more accurate to set up camera hotkeys. Almost all pros do. I'm mid masters and use tab as my base camera (rebinded from backspace) so I agree to an extent. I just wish I learned location hotkeys when I was new to starcraft.

Answer (score -1):

If you are having this issue its because you have bad habits and are being lazy. Make it a habbit to shift click back to a mineral patch after building/warping in things.