# Is there a hotkey to select an idle worker, but not jump to its location?

Tags: starcraft-2

I seem to remember from Age of Empires that you could select an idle worker without the screen repositioniong, and I think the minimap would also ping the location of that worker. Is there a way to do that in Starcraft 2?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118662/how-to-select-idle-worker-without-the-screen-jumping-to-the-worker